# Change year variable in dataframe depending on season

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like following:

```
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(Month=c(sort(sample(1:12, 10)),
                         sort(sample(1:12, 10)),
                         sort(sample(1:12, 10))),
                 Year=c(rep(2007, 10), 
                        rep(2010, 10), 
                        rep(2011, 10)))
```

Head of `df`:

```
  Month Year
1     1 2007
2     3 2007
3     4 2007
4     5 2007
5     6 2007
6     7 2007
```

I need to recode the year variable depending on season, for example if month is January and year is 2013, then year should be be recoded to 2012/2013. For January-June, year should be recoded to 2012/2013, and for July-December year should be recoded to 2013/2014.

`df` should therefore be recoded as below. Note that some months are missing and some years are missing:

```
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(Month=c(sort(sample(1:12, 10)),
                         sort(sample(1:12, 10)),
                         sort(sample(1:12, 10))),
                 Year=c(rep(2007, 10), 
                        rep(2010, 10), 
                        rep(2011, 10)),                   
                 Year.Seasonal=c(rep('2006/2007', 5),
                                 rep('2007/2008', 5),
                                 rep('2009/2010', 6),
                                 rep('2010/2011', 9),
                                 rep('2011/2012', 5)))
```

Head of recoded `df`:

```
  Month Year Year.Seasonal
1     1 2007     2006/2007
2     3 2007     2006/2007
3     4 2007     2006/2007
4     5 2007     2006/2007
5     6 2007     2006/2007
6     7 2007     2007/2008
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- within(df,season <- paste(Year - (Month <= 6),
                                Year + (Month > 6),sep="/"))
head(df)
  Month Year    season
1     1 2007 2006/2007
2     3 2007 2006/2007
3     4 2007 2006/2007
4     5 2007 2006/2007
5     6 2007 2006/2007
6     7 2007 2007/2008
```

Comment: Very nice way of pasting the strings! And I should remember to use within more often.

Comment: many thanks, I was thinking this would be way more complicated than it actually was.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution using `ifelse()` - If `Month` is less than 7 then that will be previous season, if not then next season. Function `paste()` will put together years.

```
df$Year.Seasonal<-ifelse(df$Month<7,
     paste(df$Year-1,df$Year,sep="/"),paste(df$Year,df$Year+1,sep="/"))

> head(df)
  Month Year Year.Seasonal
1     1 2007     2006/2007
2     3 2007     2006/2007
3     4 2007     2006/2007
4     5 2007     2006/2007
5     6 2007     2006/2007
6     7 2007     2007/2008
```

Comment: Why not just use `df$Month<7`?

Comment: @Hemmo You are right - sometimes just thinking too complicated :D

Comment: Happens to me quite often :)